Understand ferrite core effect - How to derive its common mode impedance?
I would like to understand the "mechanics" of a ferrite core.
Id like to know how it blocks common mode currents when placed on a cable with multiple wires.
I know that the ferrite, placed around a cable, introduces a impedance to that cable.
The impedance, in first approximation, is of inductive nature, that is clear to me as well.
But Id like to undestand how that impedance is "formed" and if there is a formula like there is a formula for calculating the impedance of an inductor (coil) for instance. There, the magnetic field and the geometry is mainly dictating the results. That is because of Faraday's Law.
Is there a similar approach to understand the effect of a ferite core?
Which force acts on the common mode current?

If it's clear that an impedance is introduced, why is it unclear that CM currents are (partially) blocked? Maybe you mean that it impedes CM current but lets differential currents pass unhindered? Could that be your real question?

I wanted to know the mechanism how the impedance is "formed". With the answer below it is obvious to me now. It is again Faraday's Law which is at work.

Would a physical explanation of soft magnetism help in that regard?

@TimWilliams I am not sure what you mean.

Let's go through a series of geometrical changes to the cable to see what is going on:

You pass a several conductor cable through the hole of a ferrite ring bead.

You remove the cable harness, so now you are left with several (let's keep it at two for the sake of simplicity) wires that go through the bead hole in parallel. (first image below)

You bend the wires to the side. They still each make one turn through the bead hole. (middle sketch)

This geometry is very reminiscent of a transformer (right image). In a transformer, when you send current into the left dotted terminal, the core flux tries to stay small by inducing an equivalent current flowing out of the right dotted terminal. This is what impedes the common-mode currents in your cable. The transformer action tries to sum up the currents entering one side of the bead hole to zero.



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

It's a not-uncommon misconception that "turns" counts loops made in the wire locally; but straight wires count too. For a toroidal core geometry, as a ferrite bead has, the turns count (winding number) is the number of passes a given wire makes through the center hole.  A bead on a straight wire is one turn; if you like, the turn closes in the loop back around those wires, somehow or another; there exists a CM return path. Indeed, we have a 1t:1t transformer in this case, and because the "windings" are together in a single cable, the coupling factor is quite reasonable.

@TimWilliams Yeah the middle transformation I offer is merely to make the equivalence with the 1t:1t transformer more readily apparent.
